# Make a copy of the live site for localhost testing

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I'd like to copy my live site so I can run it on localhost and test some modules before installing them on the livesite.

Is there a step-by-step way to do this? I have access to PHPyAdmin, so I can easily export the database. I know there's more to it than just exporting, thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with the [backup and migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate). If you have lots of dynamic content you should be using this module to schedule a backup on cron jobs too.

Before I learned how to use the MySQL command line, because phpmyadmin has an import file size limit, I would compress a whole website with the backups in a private file path and move it to a new server. Then I just remove the database settings and install a new installation of Drupal. After I will enable the backup and migrate module and restore that last database.

Comment: Does it work flawlessly? As smooth as a baby's bottom?

Comment: Yes, you create to Drupal sites on different servers. Export from one and import into the other. I do it all the time.

Comment: I trust you but will this also work if I run it on localhost?

Comment: I run it on my localhost then when my website if finished I FTP a zip archive to the remote server. It's good stuff and great for development because you can create a backup in seconds every time a key part is built on the site.

Comment: Great! Will give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

If you're ever so inclined you could also use [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) to sync and deploy websites.

If you're not familiar with [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) (*drupal shell*) it's a command line that provides a plethora of functionality via the command line.

More specifically related to your question, check out this drupal node on sync'ing.

- *Using drush to synchronize and deploy sites: http://drupal.org/node/670460*

Drush even has a built in command for exporting databases:

`drush sql-dump {database name} >> {path}`

For a full list of commands checkout the [drush website](http://drush.ws).